# Problems with Jade, Unexpected character #

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, pug

I keep getting: `.../views/index.jade:20 18| alert(error) 19| }) > 20| server.on('warning',function(warning){ 21| alert(warning) 22| }) 23| var num = -1 Unexpected character # expected ' ', '\n', ',', '!' or '='`

This is my jade file:

```
extends layout


block content
    #splash(style='z-index: 3120; position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; min-height:100%; background-color:#444;')
        img(src="/stylesheets/some.png", style='display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:10%;')
    div.row
        #welcome
        div.row
            #joined.small-6.columns
            #finished.small-6.columns
    script
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var server = io.connect()
        $.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0}
        var userName = "none"
        server.on('error',function(error){
            alert(error)
        })
        server.on('warning',function(warning){
            alert(warning)
        })
        var num = -1
        server.on('welcome', function(data){
            userName = data.name
            num = data.num
            $("#splash").delay(2000)
                .queue(function(n){
                $(this).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    $(this).remove()
                    $("#welcome").html("Welcome "+data.name)
                    $("#welcome").fadeIn(1000)
                    $("#welcome").delay(2000)
                        .queue(function(n){
                            $(this).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                                $(this).remove()
                            })
                            n()
                        })
                })
                n()
            })
        })
        server.on('joined', function(name){
            num += 1
            $("#joined").append("<p>"+name+" joined</p>")
            $("#joined p").last().delay(1000)
                .queue(function(n){
                    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function (){
                        $(this).remove()
                    })
                    n()
                })
        })
        server.on('finished', function(name){
            num -= 1
            $("#finished").append("<p>"+name+" logged out</p>")
            $("#finished p").last().delay(1000)
                .queue(function(n) {
                    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                        $(this).remove()
                    })
                    n()
                })
        })
    })
```

What am I doing wrong? I cant figure it out. This used to work with an earlier version. That version also allowed to write normal javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### jade [github readme.md](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/README.md):

> Jade version 0.31.0 deprecated implicit text only support for scripts and styles. To fix this all you need to do is **add a . character after the script or style tag**.

#### And jade [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#blockinatag):

> Often you might want large blocks of text within a tag. A good example is with inline scripts or styles. To do this, **just add a . after the tag (with no preceding space)**

Write `script.` instead of `script`

Comment: Thank you sir! I would have been stuck trying to fix this for ages. Strange decision to change this in my opinion. It is also agains the semantic versioning. They are introducing backwards incompatible changes in a subversion, not major. Anyways, thanks!